# CakePHP 3.x: Accessing other controller's function

Tags: cakephp, controller

I am fairly new to CakePHP and been trying to tutor myself for around 5 days now.

I have 2 controllers namely UsersController and BlogsController.
I made a custom function inside the UsersController, basically an if else. For the 'else' part, I wanted to execute a code which requires me to access the delete() of BlogsController all the way from UsersController. I do not know if Trait RequestAction is deprecated already because the title had a strike through lol.

Any advice on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to delete Blogs related to User, if User is deleted ?

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536879/how-to-access-a-controller-action-from-within-another-controllers-action**